# Почему не срабатывает html5 валидация формы на iphone?

Tags: html5, iphone

```
<form id="form2" class="mfp-with-anim mfp-hide formular">
    <p>Обратный звонок</p>
    <span>Введите ваше имя:</span>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" pattern="^[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z]+$" required="true" /><br />
    <span>Введите ваш номер:</span>
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон" pattern="^((8|\+3)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$" required="true" /><br />
    <button>Перезвоните мне</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="text" value="Обратный звонок">
</form>
```

Везде срабатывает регулярное выражение, а вот на iPhone - нет. Отправляется пустая форма

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно посмотреть [поддержку атрибута `pattern` браузерами](http://caniuse.com/#search=pattern) и заметить, что:

> Safari поддерживает атрибут pattern, однако позволяет отправку формы, если введенное значение не соответствует pattern.

---

В качестве альтернативы можно обратить внимание на плагин [h5Validate](https://github.com/ericelliott/h5Validate).

**Поддерживаемые платформы:**

> - PC: IE 9, 8, 7, 6, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera. Проверено на Windows 7 и Mac.
> - Mobile: iPhone, Android, Palm WebOS

**Пример использования:**

> Вставьте следующий код перед закрывающим тегом `</body>` на любой
>   странице с HTML5 формой. Если в ней используются правила валидации,
>   все заработает, как по волшебству.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.h5validate.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').h5Validate();
});
</script>
```

---

**Ваш пример с использованием плагина:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').h5Validate({
    errorClass: 'error'
  });
});
```

```css
.error {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/ericelliott/h5Validate/master/jquery.h5validate.js"></script>
<form id="form2" class="mfp-with-anim mfp-hide formular">
  <p>Обратный звонок</p>
  <span>Введите ваше имя:</span>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" pattern="^[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z]+$" required="true" />
  <br />
  <span>Введите ваш номер:</span>
  <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон" pattern="^((8|\+3)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$" required="true" />
  <br />
  <button>Перезвоните мне</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="text" value="Обратный звонок">
</form>
```